# Why can't i stop my service?

Tags: android

this is my service, i want it to be sticky. i am trying to kill the service using :

```
context.stopService(new Intent(context, HauntedSoundService.class));`
```

however, the audio still keeps playing.

```
public class HauntedSoundService extends Service {
Context context = this;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;// this make the service sticky which prevents it
                        // from getting killed by advanced task killers
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // volume full
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);
    // volume full
    // play audio
    final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create((context), R.raw.cry); // -<
    mp2.setLooping(false);
    mp2.start();
    // play audio
  }
}
```

Comment: How does the `onDestroy()` method of the service look like?

Comment: i have already posted the full code

Comment: Well, you have to release all the audio/media resources in the service's `onDestroy()`.

Comment: @Cassie, these resources always have stop method. Just enter the name of your parameter and your IDE will give you a hint

Comment: Stopping a service doesn't kill any related tasks that its already started, like streaming media.  Your service needs to do that explicitly when it detects it's been stopped.

Comment: tried stopping mp1 already on onDestroy, doesnt work